# app crashed for using com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch

Tags: java, android-studio

My problem is when i click sign in button in my app then my app go to another activity called welcome activity.But when go to welcome activity my app crashed . And give some error. I am not understand about this error. So please help me from this situation.

Hare is my code for **welcome Activity**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.print.PrinterId;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation;
import com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class Welcome extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener
{

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE=7000;
    private static final int PLAY_SERIVICES_RES_REQUEST=7001;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location lastLocation;

    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL=5000;
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL=3000;
    private static int DISPLACEMENT=10;

    DatabaseReference drivers;
    GeoFire geoFire;
    Marker mCurrent;
    MaterialAnimatedSwitch location_switch;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
         mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //init view..
        location_switch=(MaterialAnimatedSwitch) findViewById(R.id.location_switch);
        location_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MaterialAnimatedSwitch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(boolean isOnline) {
                if(isOnline)
                {
                    startLocationUpdate();
                    displayLocation();
                    Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are Online",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else
                {
                    stopLocationUpdate();
                    mCurrent.remove();
                    Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are Offline",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        //Geo fire

        drivers= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Drivers");
        geoFire=new GeoFire(drivers);
        setUpLocation();
    }

    //we request run time permission ,we need override OnRequestPermission Result..


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if(grantResults.length>0&&grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    if(checkPlayServices())
                    {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                        createLocationRequest();
                        if(location_switch.isChecked())
                            displayLocation();
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private void setUpLocation() {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
           //Request Runtime permission...
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            },MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        else
        {
                if(checkPlayServices())
                {
                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    createLocationRequest();
                    if(location_switch.isChecked())
                        displayLocation();
                }
        }
    }

    private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest=new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    }

    private void buildGoogleApiClient() {

        mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect(); //Connected Google api client.....
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode= GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(resultCode!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode))
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode,this,PLAY_SERIVICES_RES_REQUEST).show();
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return false;

        }

        return true;
    }

    private void stopLocationUpdate() {

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return;
        }

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);

    }

    private void displayLocation() {

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return;
        }

        lastLocation=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if(lastLocation!=null)
        {
            if(location_switch.isChecked())
            {
                final double latitude=lastLocation.getLatitude();
                final double longitude=lastLocation.getLongitude();

                //update firebase..
                geoFire.setLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                        //add marker
                        if(mCurrent!=null)
                            mCurrent.remove();//marker remove already
                        mCurrent=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car))
                                                .position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
                                                .title("YOU"));
                        //Move camera from this position..
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,longitude),15.0f));

                        //draw animated rotated marker..
                        rotateMarker(mCurrent,-360,mMap);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("ERROR","Cannot get your location");
        }

    }

    private void rotateMarker(final Marker mCurrent, final float i, GoogleMap mMap) {

        final Handler handler=new Handler();
        final long start= SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final float startRotation=mCurrent.getRotation();
        final long duration=1500;

        final Interpolator interpolator=new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed=SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-start;
                float t=interpolator.getInterpolation((float)elapsed/duration);
                float rot=t*i+(1-t)*startRotation;

                mCurrent.setRotation(-rot>180?rot/2:rot);

                if(t<1.0)
                {
                    handler.postDelayed(this,16);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void startLocationUpdate() {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return;
        }

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lastLocation=location;
        displayLocation();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        displayLocation();
        startLocationUpdate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {


    }
}
```

Hare is my **activity_welcome** layout:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Welcome" >



    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch
                android:id="@+id/location_switch"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:icon_release="@drawable/ic_location_off"
                app:icon_press="@drawable/ic_location_on"
                app:base_release_color="@color/baseReleaseColor"
                app:base_press_color="@color/basePress"
                app:ball_release_color="@color/ballReleaseColor"
                app:ball_press_color="@android:color/white"
                />




        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</fragment>
```

Hare is my **ERROR**

```
    Process: com.example.ubarclone, PID: 15109
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ubarclone/com.example.ubarclone.Welcome}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:420)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2771)
        at com.example.ubarclone.Welcome.onCreate(Welcome.java:72)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:734)
        at com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.painter.IconPainter.initBitmap(IconPainter.java:41)
        at com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.painter.IconPainter.init(IconPainter.java:36)
        at com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.painter.IconPainter.<init>(IconPainter.java:30)
        at com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.painter.IconPressPainter.<init>(IconPressPainter.java:30)
        at com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch.initPainters(MaterialAnimatedSwitch.java:79)
        at com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch.init(MaterialAnimatedSwitch.java:65)
        at com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch.init(MaterialAnimatedSwitch.java:90)
        at com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch.<init>(MaterialAnimatedSwitch.java:54)
```

For better understand provide screenshot :
[image: Error]

This error show in 72 number line in welcome Activity. Here is a image for 72 number line :
[image]

Hare is my **Module:app** for dependencies :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ubarclone"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //metarial edit text..
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"


    //add library for firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'

    //loading dialog dependency
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'

    //for maps
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

    //geofire
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:3.0.0'

    //for switch active map an inactive maps..
    implementation'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    // the above lib may be old dependencies version
}
```

please Help me from this situation ...

Comment: does the answer below help to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

From the crash stacktrace and from material-animated-switch source code it turns out that there is an issue with the `@drawable/ic_location_off` icon. The method `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` that is used by the library to load the drawable returns null therefore it is not possible to rescale the image according to the `11dp` icon size needed.

Please make sure it is defined in the `res/drawable` folder.